# Apple Watch measures your heart rhythm when you are not on the go

Tags: ios, apple-watch, watchos

I discovered at today, my Apple Watch S2 measures my heart rhythm when you are not on the go. For example, I was sleeping at 02:35 AM , today. But it measured 135 BPM heart rate an it is was standing in the drawer. Are anyone encountered with this issue ? Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what the watch is designed to do - always monitor the pulse whether you are on the go or not. What does "standing in the drawer" mean - are you saying it didn't detect being off your wrist? _( just use the edit link above to improve the details or clarify what the situation is so people can answer based on the body of the question without wading through comments)_

Comment: If you were wearing the watch while sleeping, and it showed a BPM of 135, I would suggest you see a cardiologist ASAP.

Comment: If you were not wearing the watch at 2:35am ("it was standing in the drawer") and you're positive it measured a heart rate at that time (meaning you didn't misread the date or time of the measurement) then my guess is the Watch is defective and should be returned to Apple.

Comment: I did not wear it while I'm sleeping. As I told, I stored it in a drawer to protect at nights. I determined that, if I close the background app refresh for "Pulse" in Apple Watch app, everything goes perfect. I think that's kind of weird. I read the times correctly.